# Filtering second select list based on first select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have some time zones in a second select list, that I want to filter by a first select list that contains countries.

Select list 1 (Just some example time zones and countries):

```
<select id="field_81" class="form-control" name="field_81" required>
    <option value="">Please select your country</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
</select>
```

Select list 2:

```
<select id="field_414" name="field_414" required>
    <option value="">Please select your timezone</option>
    <option value="Africa/Abidjan" data-country="Cote d'Ivoire">Africa/Abidjan</option>
    <option value="Africa/Accra" data-country="Ghana">Africa/Accra</option>
    <option value="Africa/Addis_Ababa" data-country="Ethiopia">Africa/Addis_Ababa</option>
    <option value="Africa/Algiers" data-country="Algeria">Africa/Algiers</option>
    <option value="Africa/Asmara" data-country="Eritrea">Africa/Asmara</option>
    <option value="Africa/Bamako" data-country="Mali">Africa/Bamako</option>
    <option value="Africa/Bangui" data-country="Central African Republic">Africa/Bangui</option>
</select>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
<script>
    jQuery("#field_81").change(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).data('options') == undefined) {
            /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
            jQuery(this).data('options', jQuery('#field_414 option').clone());
        }
        var id = jQuery(this).val();
        var options = jQuery(this).data('options').filter('[data-country=' + id + ']');
        jQuery('#field_414').html(options);
    });
</script>
```

It works fine for country names that consist of a single word, but any country names with spaces do not work. I can't see where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this :

```
 [data-country=' + id + ']
```

By this :

```
[data-country="' + id + '"]
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually realised after posting it, but didn't have a chance to come back and edit the question/answer

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
var options = jQuery(this).data('options').filter('[data-country=' + id + ']');
```

to

```
var options = jQuery(this).data('options').filter('[data-country="' + id + '"]');
```